# Certain morphism between graded modules

Tags: modules, graded-rings-modules

Say we have a morphism $f=(f_{i,j}) : \oplus_{i}M_{i} \rightarrow \oplus_{j}N_{j}$ (The direct sum of graded modules is finite) and $f_{i,j}$ are morphisms of graded modules but not necessary with the same degree.
Is it possible for the kernel to be graded?
Thanks

Comment: Modules over what? Associative ring? Commutative ring? Graded in what? positive integers? non-negative integers? an arbitrary abelian group?

Comment: Say positively graded ring and of course associative.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you intend to ask? It’s certainly *possible* for the kernel to be graded. For example, the kernel could be zero, or the $M_i$ could all be concentrated in the same degree, or the $f_{i,j}$ could all have the same degree.

Comment: Of course the kernel is not zero, the $f_{i,j}$ does not have the same degree and the $M_{i}$ are not concentrated in the same degree. Sorry I did not mention this hypothesis.

Comment: Jeremy Rickard, what about if all these graded modules are generated in the same degree?

Comment: There are still easy examples. For example, take $A$-modules for $A=k[x,y]$, graded with $|x|=|y|=1$. $M_1=A$, $N_1=N_2=A/(y)$, all generated in degree zero. $f_{1,1}$ and $f_{1,2}$  induced by multiplication by $1$ and $x$ respectively. Or all sorts of similar examples based on combining graded morphisms of different degrees but with the same kernel.

Comment: Here the situation is different. I understand this type of examples. You can always shift the left modules and then all the morphisms will have the same degree, namely zero degree.